# Preventing TWebBrowser.Navigate from freezing application

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, twebbrowser

I'm using a TWebBrowser component to load an advertisement, which ends up being a flash animation.

The embedded IE seems incapable of dealing with a few of the ad-URLs, the application just becomes unresponsive and takes a large amount of CPU after initiating the navigation until I kill the task. The OnNavigateError event is not fired.

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://fra1.ib.adnxs.com/ab?enc=i2Lixr4uzT9K8v6yq0PKP99PjZduEts_SvL-sqtDyj-LYuLGvi7NP1K85HoPuMws2Qp8eWrwMlELbSp'
   + 'UAAAAAAFILgDLCAAAHwUAAAIAAAAfbC4Bu9YGAAAAAQBVU0QAVVNEAKAAWALAYAAAGNsBAQUAAQIAAIoA3igbuwAAAAA.&cnd=%218ylhdAitjcQCEJ_YuQkYACC7rRsw'
   + 'ADgAQABInwpQgZC5AVgAYOEEaABwCHjiWoABNIgBFpABAZgBAaABAagBArABALkBYXNY_Hb6xj_BAYti4sa-Ls0_yQE5kG67FLncP9kBUdobfGEy6T_gAQD1AZqZmT8.&'
   + 'ccd=%21DQZ2OAitjcQCEJ_YuQkYu60bIAA.&udj=uf%28%27a%27%2C+387951%2C+1412066571%29%3Buf%28%27c%27%2C+5310125%2C+1412066571%29%3Buf%2'
   + '8%27r%27%2C+19819551%2C+1412066571%29%3B&vpid=1&apid=1&referrer=redacted&custom_macro=CP_ID%5E5310125&media_subtypes=1&ct=16&rsrc'
   + '=3&dlo=1&pp=%%pricepaid%');
end;
```

Clearly there is something wrong with the advertisement itself since it doesn't load in IE either, it shows a blank page with neither content nor an error. However on the Delphi side I would like the navigation to not freeze the application in any case, is there a way for me to catch whatever error occurs there and handle it properly ?

Comment: Hm, so our task is to investigate what's wrong with that suspicious site ? I won't do that, because there can be anything, from *harmless* [`infinite loop`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269786/960757) to some malware. As you may guess, that *harmless* infinite loop is not *an error*.

Comment: @TLama Fair enough, my reasoning was that since it loads fine in FF/Chrome it must be some IE-specific error and thus I should be able to handle it somehow.

Comment: maybe not quite what you want but did you try using `TWebBrowser.Stop` combined with a `TTimer`?

Comment: The application seems to be caught in an infinite loop so neither Timers nor Threads nor anything will execute anymore.

Comment: Sometime back we were facing a IE issue, our application was not responding on machines that were having IE9, IE10 or IE11. The application was running stable on IE8.

Comment: Use your debugging tools to discover precisely where your program gets stuck. Then you can start thinking of ways to either avoid getting there or get yourself out. Right now, though, you don't yet know the full problem.

Comment: @RobKennedy The last line of VCL code is the call to DispatchMessageW with a WM_APP+2 message, which leads to entries from MSHTML.DLL in the callstack until one of them seems to not return. I'm not really sure where to go from there.